# Why do people delete their answer when criticised?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

I have encountered this behavior multiple times when asking questions on Stack Overflow.

There are times when I get sloppy, poor answers to my questions. When I start explaining (in comments) why that certain answer is simply wrong or that it deviates from the subject posted, the user simply deletes his answer with a twist of fingers.

Some answers are simply being toasted to my question as I've had hard times explaining the user that his answer simply proves that he didn't even read my question fully.

For example if my question gets two sloppy answers that do not help in any way (it happened to me and after I confronted those answers, both users deleted them)
many people browsing through `Newest` section would notice that my question has actually 2 answers already and may be tempted to not even read it anymore.

After the question stops being "hot", the users (that posted) delete their both answers (after being confronted and explained that their answers serve no good, and maybe worse) my question remains with no answer, probably for good.

**Why deleting your answer is so easy?**

Questions cannot be deleted that easily. Why would answers be? After all, effort is being put in questions as well. And there is always the `edit` button for answers.

Comment: accepted answers also can't be deleted easily - only by diamond moderators or (only if negative score) by 3 votes from 20k users

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> There are times when I get sloppy, poor answers to my questions. When I start explaining (in comments) why that certain answer is simply wrong or that it deviates from the subject posted, the user simply deletes his answer with a twist of fingers.

Which means your comments are getting through

> Some answers are simply being toasted to my question as I've had hard times explaining the user that his answer simply proves that he didn't even read my question fully.

*excellent*. Then they go away.

> After the question stops being "hot", the users (that posted) delete their both answers (after being confronted and explained that their answers serve no good, and maybe worse) my question remains with no answer, probably for good.

Eh, maybe if your target audience relies entirely on the front page. But here's the amusing part - if you feel you can clarify the question, do so, and it. I suppose you could also offer a bounty if its that important. Maybe its cause I spend my time on smaller sites, but I've sometimes gotten great answers *years* after the fact. One of my popular answers basically was to a question 2 years old (and I snuck my answer in since a self answered question would have been closed as dupe anyway. And the existing answers were lacking).

So... that's the system working as designed. Good titles and appropriate tags are going to be more helpful than what other people do.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I've changed my perspective somehow now. Meanwhile, I am counting the downvotes on my question haha.

Comment: @CatalinGhita So take those votes as a suggestion to improve your question.  Cause if your getting answers that don’t apply to your question then it’s very likely the question itself isn’t clear

Comment: @Ramhound I must contradict you. If the question is well phrased there still might be some low quality answers out there. Ideally, the quality of the question should not affect the quality of the answer. Yes, if the question is unclear this might lead to unclear answers. But I was referring to sloppy low quality answers that might occur and you can't blame the asker for those as well.

Comment: @CatalinGhita wasn’t blaming the author was blaming the question.  Without seeing the answers you received, difficult to actually suggest anything but, to improve the clarity of the question. If you are getting irrelevant answers, there is a good chance, your question needs to be clarified

Comment: @Ramhound Your first impression is fair but imagine this: I asked a question and throughout the post I specifically stated which methods of solving the problem I've tried. Aditionally I added that one of them should not be used as it would lead to bad memory management and therefore should not be suggested. Yet after 5 minutes I got an answer suggesting exactly that method. Therefore the user that answered did not even take the effort of reading my question fully..to which I devoted time to express. Some hours later I get another similar answer with a similar method

Comment: I couldn’t find any question you submitted that matches what you described

Comment: As the answers have been deleted, how could you?

Answer (score 6):

The user that answer you has no obligation to do so, and no obligation to keep the answer there. No one is paid to help you there.

Keep in mind some users are not english native (like me) and it happen to misunderstand a question. In such case I often delete my answer as for the community it has no value to keep a useless answer on a question. (unless Iam able to edit it to really answer you)

Comment: I don't think I implied that there should be someone paid to answer my question. It's pretty far from what I meant. And I was not referring to those answers that lack English knowledge. I was referring to bad, sloppy answers.

Comment: @CatalinGhita If this keeps happening then perhaps it has something to do with the questions themselves.